# Problem with boot Ubuntu on Acer Aspire V15 Nitro (Black Edition)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, acer

I have Acer Aspire V15 Nitro (Black Edition) with UEFI on Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I followed all the instructions explaining how to configure it to work.
 It means:

- quickstart off
- security boot disabled
- set in cmd grub as the boot loader (bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\linuxmint\grubx64.efi)

By default, Windows 10 starts every time.

Finally, GRUB 2 does not start by default. To enable ubuntu I have to perform a breakneck mission. DO I start the computer, quickly click F12 (boot menu), it opens and I see two (apparently) equal entries named "Windows Boot Manager" (see below)

[image]

By trial and error I finally clicked 2. and GRUB started ... Only this way I can enable Ubuntu.

My BIOS menu looks like this:

[image]

I would like to start GRUB by default. Any ideas?

Comment: @jwcooper It means I set bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\linuxmint\grubx64.efi

Comment: I checked Gparted. Boot loader is on one partition, correct partition. The same partition with windows and ubuntu. There is no boot partition on the second disk.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? And then set "trust" from within UEFI for the ubuntu (unknown) entry? All Acer need "trust" setting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot many Acer also need UEFI update & if SSD, firmware update. Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504

Comment: @oldfred The case described https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot here is the same as mine. "but if you need Ubuntu when you power on the Laptop press the F12 key repeatedly until the" Boot Manager's "window opens." That's the way I need to start ubuntu. My question is whether it can be avoided and done more simply.

Comment: Did you set "trust" on Ubuntu entry from UEFI. You then should be able to move that entry to first in UEFI boot order with efibootmgr. Some systems only let change order with UEFI and reset efibootmgr changes on boot.

Comment: @oldfred I did and now it works! Thank you! You should solution write as Answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Acer typically required that you have latest UEFI from Acer for your system and systems with SSD need latest firmware from SSD vendor.

Acer has an unique requirement of setting "trust" on the "ubuntu" UEFI boot entry.

It may be shown as unknown until trust is set. You have to create an UEFI password & turn on UEFI secure boot to set trust. Be sure not to forget UEFI password, or reset to blank when done.

Other models, but Acer has similar UEFI for all systems.

[Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Acer Cloudbook shows screen for selecting trust, shows typical screens for all Acer

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/340-ubuntu-install-acer-aspire-cloudbook-431

https://community.acer.com/en/categories/predator

Answer (score 0):

When your computer is booting press whatever the bios option key is could be f11 or del couple of other options. There is often a way to adjust boot order. If your firmware gives you that option you should be able to move GRUB to the top position. Could also be called ubuntu instead of grub.

Comment: Ohh I forgot. When I open the bootlist in the BIOS I have only one Windows Boot Manager item. Of course, HDD, SSD, USB, etc. are on the list. Windows Boot Manager is top of the list. It's hard to explain. I will take 2 photos of what can be seen in the BIOS and what in the bootmenu