# Problem installing Ubuntu from bootable USB

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm having problems installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10 on my Acer Swift 3 laptop. I've put Ubuntu onto a bootable USB, and am able to select "install Ubuntu", but after setting up the keyboard, I'm told I don't have enough space to install Ubuntu. It seems that it is only detecting the space I have on my 4GB USB drive, when I've cleared 40GB on my SSD to install ubuntu.

How can I get it to recognise my SSD?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most systems need UEFI update and SSD firmware update. You may need to change drive from RAID/Intel RST to AHCI. Acer also need "trust" setting in UEFI after install. Acer Swift 3
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2370998 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047065/fail-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-from-usb-to-a-brand-new-acer-swift-1 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172012/problem-with-boot-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-v15-nitro-black-edition?noredirect=1#comment1956903_1172012

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, needed to set a password in bios